# COM+ events with c# and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, com+

I'm trying to get access to certain parts of my application through COM, mainly because I need  a Delphi application to be able to invoke certain services on the .NET application.

I've managed to expose some methods via COM inheriting from ServicedComponent class and its working fine.

Now I need to be able to raise events to the client so I can alert him when certain things occur. I currently have something like this:

```
public interface IEvents
{
  void OnMessage();
}

[EventClass]    
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyEventsClass : ServicedComponent, IEvents
{
  public void OnMessage()
  {
  }
}
```

but when I import the TypeLibrary from Delphi I get this:

```
IEvents = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{E7605303-F968-3509-829B-BF70084053C4}']
    procedure OnMessage; safecall;
  end;

IEventsDisp = dispinterface
    ['{E7605303-F968-3509-829B-BF70084053C4}']
    procedure OnMessage; dispid 1610743808;
  end;
```

which I don't really know how to use. I was expecting an IUnknown interface that I can implement and provide to the service through a MyService.Register(IEvents events)...

I think I'm completely lost here... Any advice or reference about how to properly implement COM+ events with .NET?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unsure of what exactly is the use for EventClass by I've discovered you don't need to use it. I simply have declared this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IMyEventIface
{
}
```

And with that the interface is exported as an IUnknown interface to Delphi.

Then you define a method on your ServicedComponent class which a connect signature like this:

```
public void Connect(IMyEventIface eventHandler)
{
  mEvents.Add(eventHandler);
}
```

which left you to manually handle the invoke of each client event handler but is the only way I've found.